# Issue with Comparing socket addresses

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, chat, winsock2

I am currently working on a UDP application that allows two users to talk to eachother using the winsock librarary. Currently when my program runs, it first saves the sockaddress to a vector and then when the user sends a message it compares the address to the first address in the vector. When I debug and compare the values being compared they are exactly the same yet my if statment goes to the else (it thinks that the addresses dont equal each other)

this is the code I have:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>

sockaddr    clientAddress;

recvfrom( hSocket, msg, MAXLINE, 0, &clientAddress, &cbClientAddress );

myVector.pushback(clientAddress);

if (&clientAddresses[0] == &clientAddress)
{
//is the same address
}
else
{
//not the same address
}
```

Ive also tried being more specific with using `.sa_data` after the `clientAddress[0]` and `&clientAddress.`

Thanks

Comment: I suspect a problem around the initialization of `cbClientAddress` (which should be of type `socklen_t` and comparing the wrong length. You should be initializating this variable to `sizeof(clientAddress)` before the call to `recvfrom` and afterwards comparing only the number of bytes that are actually used in the structure, not comparing the entire structure. Can you show how you initialize `cbClientAddress`?

Comment: @Celada I do initialize the variable to sizeof(clientAddress) before I add it to the vector. I was just using the clientAddress as a unique identifier for the connection

Comment: By the way, I strongly not recommend doing this, unless you have no choice. You should use the source address only as the address to reply to and for logging/authorization purposes. You should never use it to identify a client unless you have no choice.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - the program is only for personal use and I need to log the user so that I can redirect the messages to the different clients connected to the server

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I do agree with you 100% tho that if this was for a company or something not for personal use I wouldnt want to gather that information

Comment: You should redirect the messages based on which client sent it, not which address they sent it from! TCP has a mechanism to identify clients based on a 4-tuple, but UDP does not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I get TCP is better for this but I just wanted to try making an application using the UDP. The reason why I'm comparing it on the address that it came from becuase i check to see if the address equals the person sending it. if match dont send and use the other address in the vector.

Comment: Right, but that's broken. You shouldn't be matching based on the address the message was sent from but based on which client sent it. If your messaging-over-UDP protocol gives you no way to know which client sent a message, it's broken and you should fix it. TCP does allow you to use a 4-tuple as a connection identifier, but UDP is connectionless and does not allow you to do this. It will break under real world conditions. If you want "connections" and client identifiers, you have to code them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues:

- Before the call to `recvfrom`, you need to initialize `cbClientAddress` (of type `socklen_t`) to the number of bytes of address information you are ready to receive, like this:

  ```
   struct sockaddr clientAddress;
   socklen_t cbClientAddress;

   cbClientAddress = sizeof(clientAddress);
   recvfrom(hSocket, msg, MAXLINE, 0, &clientAddress, &cbClientAddress);
  ```
- After the call, `cbClientAddress` will be overwritten with the actual length of the address that was received. This will be shorter than `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`. In fact it will be equal to `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` because this is a UDP/IP socket.
- You must compare only the part of the structure that actually contains data, not the whole structure. The unused portion of the structure (the difference in size between `struct sockaddr_in` and `struct sockaddr`) might be garbage. You don't want to compare it. This will necessitate not only memorizing the contents of the structure itself in a vector, but also the significant length.
- When comparing the saved address against the one you've just received, use this kind of pseudocode. Don't try to compare the whole structure (including trailing unused portions).

  ```
  if (
      (saved_length == this_length) &&
      (memcmp(saved_sockaddr, this_sockaddr, this_length) == 0)
  ) {
      it's a match
  }
  ```
- Your code `&clientAddresses[0] == &clientAddress` checks if the addresses of the structures are equal. This means you're testing to see if it's *the same structure* instead of what you want, which is testing if it's *a structure with the same contents*. Use `memcmp` as per the pseudocode above to compare the contents.